# Can't access my homepage

Tags: joomla-3.5, bugs

I was deleting some menu items when I accidentally set another menu as my homepage, and now I can't uncheck.
It looks like two menu items are set as homepage, and therefore I can't access my homepage. How is this even supposed to happen? I thought that when you click on a star the other is automatically unchecked.
I've already tried to uncheck one of them, but it says that at least one menu item must be set as default.I don't have the faintest idea of what to do.
I'll post a screenshot below.
I'm sorry if I'm missing something here, I'm quite new to Joomla.
The link to the website is http://www.associacaoproesporte.org.br/index.php/pt-br/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you should not be able to have a homepage in your trash.

Try going into your database and going to the `menu` table.

This has a column called `home`.  Make sure the deleted one has a value of 0 and the default has a value of 1.

There **should** be a 1 in this column next to each language homepage, and also the default homepage.  Language ones will have the language field filled in.

I was able to replicate your problem by adding an additional 1 to a deleted menu item, so it looks like you have somehow corrupted your database.

Probably sensible to make a backup before fiddling in your database, though I think the above should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've changed the value of the deleted one and now the website works perfectly fine.